# How to add Gist into Blogger

Tags: html, blogger, gist

It's my first time to add a python script into by blog, after some Googling i found that i easiest way is to use Gist, i posted my python script into Gist, i choose a python language  and create public Gist, the result "Embed this gist" was a javascript

```
<script src="https://gist.github.com/anonymous/7842985.js"></script>
```

now when i paste this code into my blog and click on preview or publish, nothing appear but the same java script !
any idea please .

Comment: what is the output u get?what do u mean by same javascript?

Comment: @Michel when i publish the blog or click on preview it shows  <script src="https://gist.github.com/anonymous/7842985.js"></script>

Answer (score 12, accepted):

1.Sign in to blogger and create/edit a post

2.Click on `"HTML"` and not `"compose"` and then paste your script.The save without again clicking on compose.

[image]
<sub>(source: [ctrlv.in](https://img.ctrlv.in/img/52a6ade8f01a9.jpg))</sub>

Comment: In Dynamic view templates , this doesn't work, switched to other theme and worked

Comment: If we switch to HTML mode and paste the embed URL, it is not rendered when we switch to WYSIWYG mode. Any tricks to see the preview in the editor?

Answer (score 5):

Just change to “Interpret typed HTML” under Post Options -> Compose Settings in blogger

Answer (score 3):

You need to switch to *HTML* mode instead of *WYSIWYG editor*. Then add the JavaScript code in place you need.

However if you switch back to *Compose* mode the snippet won't appear!
You have to click *Preview* to see it.

Also try solution mentioned here [Issues adding github gist to my blog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18788724/issues-adding-github-gist-to-my-blogusing-google-blogger/21355714#21355714)